# Looking into providng mailing address validation services in-house. What is needed?

Tags: untagged

We are looking into validating address information in house for both security concerns and performance reasons.  My first intuition is build a *nix box with postgres sql on a separate physical machine.  **Because the information needs validation in almost real-time, what should I consider?**

As a side concern, what should I consider in obtaining and updating mailing address information?  I know there's a few providers out there that can assist, but we are trying to avoid submitting requests over WWW for privacy concerns.

Comment: Please be more specific: Do you mean physical mailing address, or email address? Do you mean validation as in "conforms to a specification", or "the intended recipient will actually get a message sent here"? etc...

Comment: What I meant by Mailing address was physical mailing address.

Comment: While this is an interesting question, it's fundamentally off topic for SF (it's really a programming question and doesn't have much to do with System Administration) so I'm going to close it as such.  Check out the Stack Overflow question I linked to in my answer though - there are a few other questions/answers over there which might help point you in the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

Validating physical mailing addresses is ***HARD*** --It's even harder than validating email addresses.

To illustrate some of the complexity, the USPS will accept all of the following:

```
John Smith
1313 Fake Street, APT 0
Anytown, NY, 12345-6789

John Smith
1313 Fake Street
Apartment 0
Anytown NY 12345

Mister Smith
1313 Fake Street
APT 0
Anytown NY
```

as valid addresses (though the first is the closest to their ideal, and the last will piss them off as lacking a ZIP code it has to be hand-coded by someone to get where it's going)

Your best bet is to hand off the address validation - for example to the [USPS address validation API](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm).  The interactive consumer interface on the USPS web site will even offer to fix up and standardize addresses for you so they match the USPS Ideal Address Format, and I assume that their API has similar functionality.

[StackOverflow had a question on this very subject -- it may help you out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134956/how-do-you-perform-address-validation)

Comment: Yeah, it was a close call between SF and SO.  I was trying to take from the stand point of a DBA as opposed to a developer because what we have is essentially a DB of addresses with separated fields (street 1, street 2, city, etc.) that must be validated after a certian period of time, so formating wouldn't exactly be as much of an issue.  But yes, I suspected that this wouldn't be so easy.  Thanks for pointing out the SO post.

Comment: @hydroparadise Yeah, it would really be OT for [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com) as well because the core question is how to validate the address programmatically - though once you know the answer to that if your DB is flexible like Postgres you could use a DB trigger to do the validation (insert long list of caveats about using network resources in a trigger here)